# Help Converting T-SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql, union

Have the following (non-straightforward) T-SQL query, which i'm trying to convert to LINQ (to be used in a L2SQL expression):

```
declare @IdAddress int = 481887

select * from 
(
    select top 3 p.* 
    from tblProCon p
    inner join vwAddressExpanded a
    on p.IdPrimaryCity = a.IdPrimaryCity
    where a.AddressType = 3
    and p.IsPro = 1
    and a.IdAddress = @IdAddress
    order by AgreeCount desc
) as Pros

union

select * from 
(
    select top 3 p.* 
    from tblProCon p
    inner join vwAddressExpanded a
    on p.IdPrimaryCity = a.IdPrimaryCity
    where a.AddressType = 3
    and p.IsPro = 0
    and a.IdAddress = @IdAddress
    order by AgreeCount desc
) as Cons

order by ispro desc, AgreeCount desc
```

In a nutshell, i have an **@IdAddress** - and i'm trying to find the **top 3 pro's** and **top 3 con's** for that address.

The above query does work as expected. I'm not entirely sure how to convert it to a LINQ query (never done unions before with LINQ). I don't even know where to start. **:)**

Query-style/Lambda accepted (prefer query-style, for readability).

Also - i have LinqPad installed - but i'm not sure how to "convert T-SQL to Linq" - is there an option for that? Bonus upvote will be awarded for that. **:)**

The above T-SQL query performs well, and this L2SQL query will be executed frequently, so it needs to perform pretty well.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var baseQuery = (from p in db.tblProCon
                join a in db.vwAddresssExpanded
                on p.IdPrimaryCity equals a.IdPrimaryCity
                where a.AddressType == (byte) AddressType.PrimaryCity &&
          a.IdAddress == idAddress
          order by p.AgreeCount descending
                select p);

var pros = baseQuery.Where(x=> x.IsPro).Take(3);
var cons = baseQuery.Where(x=> !x.IsPro).Take(3);

var results = pros
               .Union(cons)
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.IsPro)
               .ThenByDescending(x => x.AgreeCount)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: what about the `.Take()` (3 pros, 3 cons)

Comment: You should perhaps add `.Take(3)` to each of `pros` and `cons`.

Comment: @Vlad - thanks. Got it working - updated your answer to include the complete solution (for others who stumble here). You were missing the final ordering on the query. Thanks again!

Comment: If your schema is set up properly with FK's you don't really need to join them explicitly like this.

Comment: yeah, they're not - hahah. Will be fixed in v2 (EF FTW) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can call `(some query expression).Union(other query expression)`.
You can also (equivalently) write `Enumerable.Union(some query expression, other query expression)`.

Note that both expressions must return the same type.

---

AFAIK, there are no tools that automatically convert SQL to LINQ.
(For non-trivial SQL, that's a non-trivial task)

Comment: Thanks - i've written the two queries, but where do i do the `.Take()`? I need top 3 pros and top 3 cons.

Comment: @RPM: Inside the `Union` arguments.  (As part of the queries)

Comment: You're trying to UNION the `Take(3)` pros and the `Take(3)` cons.  Convert that into method calls.

Comment: Thanks for your help, got me on the right track - but i gave the answer off to @Paul Creasey for showing the actual query. Appreciate the help though. :)